# c# Avoid beep on KeyDown press?

Tags: audio, click, keydown, beep

I'm having a problem removing the beep sound when pressing the Enter key in a textbox.

This doesn't work:

```
private void textBox3_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            button1.PerformClick();               
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer!

```
 private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            //Pressing ENTER
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                button1.Select();
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");            
            }

        }
```